# Pixel alignment for trend analysis in Earth Engine

Tags: geometry, google-earth-engine, landsat

I am trying to calculate NDVI trends over time using Landsat scenes and the earth engine code below:

```
var point = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-133.49, 69.18]);
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
  .select(['B3', 'B4'])
  .filterBounds(point)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,8,'month'));

//adds ndvi as band 'B4_1'
var ndvi = function(image) {
  var nir = image.select('B4');
  var red = image.select('B3');
  var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));
  var proimage = image.addBands(ndvi);
  return proimage;
};

var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return     image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(3.154e10));
};

var stack = l5.map(ndvi).map(createTimeBand);

var linearFit = stack.select(['system:time_start','B4_1'])
.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

var linpar = {min: 0, max: [-0.01, 0.01, 5], bands: ['scale', 'scale',         'offset']};
Map.addLayer(linearFit, linpar,'fit');
Map.setCenter(-133.50, 69.19, 9);
```

However when I zoom in it seems the pixels are misaligned between scenes from different paths/rows.

[image: pixels]

I found [this code to register an image to a reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/register), but is there some way to align the geometry of a large stack of images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you can "align" the geometry of the pixels of multiple images by using [ee.Image.reproject()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagereproject) and [ee.Image.resample()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageresample) and [mapping](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_mapping) those functions over images in the collection. However, be aware that this will potentially alter/smooth the information provided in each of the original images. (Your example is for a high latitude area, where the imagery is collected from multiple overlapping satellite orbits of a [polar orbiting satellite](http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m407_707/Monteverdi/Satellite/PolarOrbiter/Polar_Orbits.html). It is best to avoid smoothing out this valuable information.)

Alternatively, you could call [ee.Image.reproject()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagereproject) and [ee.Image.resample()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageresample) on the `linearFit` image (i.e. after estimating the time series trend) to control the projection of the final result. This approach would reduce the amount of altering/smoothing, which I expect will be preferable for your time series analysis use case.

```
// Reproject using the CRS parameters of one of the original images.
var reprojected = linearFit.reproject({
  crs:'EPSG:32609', 
  crsTransform:[30,0,278985,0,-30,7849515], 
});
var resampled = reprojected.resample('bicubic');
Map.addLayer(reprojected, linpar, 'reprojected');
Map.addLayer(resampled, linpar, 'resampled');
```